# Docker seccomp not working on Kali

Tags: security, docker, linux-kernel, kernel, seccomp

I'm investigating about kernel security using Docker. I'm testing seccomp and it works very well on Debian and Ubuntu, but It's not working on Kali Linux.

Example:

I created a simple json file called `sec.json` with this content:

```
{
    "defaultAction": "SCMP_ACT_ALLOW",
        "syscalls": [
                {
                    "name": "mkdir",
                    "action": "SCMP_ACT_ERRNO"
                }
            ]
}
```

It' suppossed that running a container using seccomp and this file will produce that you are not able to use `mkdir` command inside the container. This is the docker run command:

```
docker run --rm -ti --security-opt seccomp=/path/to/sec.json ubuntu:xenial sh
```

As I said it works very well on Debian and Ubuntu, but on Kali Linux I got this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: linux seccomp: seccomp profiles are not supported on this daemon, you cannot specify a custom seccomp profile.
```

My docker-engine version is `17.05.0-ce` and my Kernel is `4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. I googled about this and is quite strange. It is suppossed that seccomp is supported if you can check this:

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep CONFIG_SECCOMP=
```

I got as a result:

```
CONFIG_SECCOMP=y
```

So it's suppossed that it's supported. What am I missing or what is the explanation about this is not working on Kali? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found this post. I'll try to answer myself:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26497

Is quite similar. I checked my `docker info` output and on Ubuntu and Debian I have the `Security Options: seccomp` and I have nothing on Kali.

The possible explanation is the `libseccomp2` package which contains the needed library is too old. Maybe if the Kali staff update the library it could be supported.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> echo 'apt::sandbox::seccomp "false";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/999seccomp

That should work.